What is this huge generalization of the Modularity Theorem?
A friend of mine wrote:

The point is of course that the Modularity Theorem (as I stated it) is/should be really just a special case of some much bigger theorem which sets up a bijection between between a certain class of varieties, and the specific kinds of (generalized) modular forms they produce. (There is exactly such a theorem/conjecture, I've forgotten its name, you can see how rusty I am!)

What is this "much bigger theorem"?  I suppose there could be more than one.
Here's how he stated the Modularity Theorem: the theorem provides a specific bijection between isogeny classes of elliptic curves defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ with conductor $N$ and integral normalized newforms of weight 2 for $\Gamma_0(N)$.

Hmm, I thought it was supposed to be part of the Langlands philosophy. But I don't know if that's what was intended here. (My understanding is that there is no precise formulation of what global Langlands over number fields should look like, and modularity is one of the few pieces of evidence.)

"A certain class of varieties" suggests a more specific result than the overall "Langlands philosophy".

Fair enough! So maybe there should be some intermediate thing that can be proven (or at least stated). I'm not at all an expert, so I hope someone else can say a bit more.

Clozel conjectured that irreducible motives are in bijection with his cuspidal algebraic automorphic representations for $GL_n$, the latter of which are surely the "generalized" modular forms in question.

Why don't you ask "your friend who wrote" this?

@AlexandreEremenko Perhaps because they pre-emptively answered it with the “I've forgotten its name”?

the Modularity Theorem (as I stated it) - How did they state the modularity theorem?  Just for elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$?  But I will guess that the more general form they meant is also often called modularity (or automorphy).

@Kimball - they stated the Modularity Theorem as follows: there's a bijection between isogeny classes of elliptic curves defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ with conductor $N$ and integral normalized newforms of weight 2 for $\Gamma_0(N)$. (To make this useful they described the bijection.)  I'll add this clue.  Can you point me to a more general form that works for some other varieties?  Are you referring to Clozel's conjecture as in sdr's comment?

You might check out the ICM plenary address of Frank Calegari "Reciprocity in the Langlands program since Fermat's Last Theorem"  available here https://math.uchicago.edu/~fcale/research.html and the excellent video of his talk. -- this (Clozel's conjecture and its refinements, which Calegari broadly refers to as Langlands reciprocity) is not about a specific class of varieties but the idea that all pure motives are associated to automorphic representations (all motivic L-functions are automorphic etc), and is a vast generalization of the specific (yet amazing) modularity you mention.

The most natural generalisation of the modularity theorem is not for varieties but rather for Galois representations (Langlands correspondence). However, every variety over a number field gives rise to Galois representations, which (conjecturally) are associated to automorphic forms. The type of the automorphic form depends (roughly) on the Mumford Tate group of the associated Galois representation.

I concur with sdr in the comments: The best interpretation of your friend's statement is the conjecture that there is a bijection between irreducible motives of rank n and cuspidal algebraic representations of $GL_n$, characterized by each motive being sent to an automorphic form with the same $L$-function. This is one of several statements that is sometimes called "Langlands reciprocity".
We can't use algebraic varieties instead of motives for multiple reasons. One can see this already in the statement of modularity, which is a bijection from elliptic curves up to isogeny to modular forms, i.e. not a bijection from isomorphism classes of algebraic varieties but rather objects in some other categories.
We could use Galois representations instead of motives here.  This would have several advantages, chiefly that there exist multiple potential definitions of the category of motives, none of which are known to have all the desired properties, but one definition of the category of Galois representations (with $\overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell$ coefficients) which has most of these desired properties. One has to put additional conditions on the Galois representations following the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture - the magic words are "finitely ramified and de Rham". One disadvantage is that this is further from the category of algebraic varieties and thus further from the original statement.
We could try to remove the "irreducible" restriction, but this isn't a good idea: "irreducible" matches up with "cuspidal" on the automorphic side, so irreducible motives correspond to cusp forms, irreducible motives can be put together to make general motives, and irreducible automorphic representations can be put together (via Eisenstein series) to make general automorphic representations, but the way they're "put together" doesn't give a bijection - there's a notion of a nontrivial extension of two motives, like a nontrivial extension of two representations, but nothing comparable on the automorphic side. (Information about the extensions does appear automorphically, but in different ways).
On the automorphic side, the restriction "algebraic" can't be removed, as non-algebraic representations don't correspond to anything in algebraic geometry.
One can replace $GL_n$ with a general group $G$, but this is not very helpful: These don't correspond to any new motives, but only to motives with $\hat{G}$-structure (e.g. a motive with $SL_n$ structure is a rank $n$ motive with trivial determinant - this isn't some incredibly exciting new structure). We lose a lot, in that the correspondence is no longer a bijection.

Thanks!  I don't see the adjective "de Rham" in the original Fontaine-Mazur paper; does this imply one of their conditions on Galois representations?  They state several conjectures, but Conjecture 1 seems to replace "de Rham" with "its restriction to every decomposition group is potentially semi-stable".

@JohnBaez "de Rham" and "potentially semi-stable" are equivalent. The fact that this is true was proven after the names were decided, I guess, and there is not complete uniformity on which one to use.
